# MySQL subquery within subquery ... is there a better way?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with about 3 million records that will continue to grow.

To check the table for new items, we're using the following:

```
SELECT m.* 
FROM some_table m  
WHERE m.account='foo' 
AND m.owner IN('bar')  
AND m.timestamp > (SELECT MAX(pointer) pointer 
                   FROM pointers 
                   WHERE account='foo' 
                   AND category='some_category' 
                   AND uuid=m.some_column_value);
```

Right now, this takes about 0.25ms for the account with the most data.  At any given time, there can be up to 256 accounts online and polling ever few seconds, per server.

I don't see an opportunity for a join here, but maybe I'm missing it.

The pointer has to be in the database for reasons, it can't be client side.

All relevant columns are indexed.

My plan B is to just limit the scope of the outer query to say the last year or so but hoping for a better way.

Looking for advice on how to optimize something like this.

Comment: It could be done with a join (`INNER JOIN (SELECT uuid, MAX(Pointer) AS Pointer FROM ... GROUP BY uuid) AS p ON p.uuid = m.some_columm_value AND p.Pointer < m.timestamp `), but if I recall correctly MySQL actually optimises this kind of correlated subquery better than a join anyway so unlikely you'd see better performance

Comment: Thank you and yep, it's 0.33ms avg with the join, so about the same results.

Comment: Hmm... maybe I can constrain by MIN(pointer) regardless of the uuid... thinking it through but that might work since we don't care about anything that has no pointer, i.e., new users.

Comment: Have you considered adding an index on the "*m.account*" column? That would considerably increase performance of the join operation.

Comment: @BillKervaski *All relevant columns are indexed.* please post table description and explain plan